# Is there a way to get the WebException Response that is being called in our catch block, but see the response in our in try block

Tags: c#, try-catch

So basically I want to be able to use the response returned from the WebExcpetion , and add it in my if statement but i'm not sure if there is a way to grab this response before it hits the catch.

```
       try
        {  
         var respnse =  //WebException Response 
        if(response == '')
          DoSomething()    
        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
        }
```

Comment: The catch is where you grab it. That's what `catch` is. That's what it does: It catches the exception. You just need to write code that does what you want. Declare `response` outside of the try/catch. If you need to do something on an exception, do it in the `catch`.

Comment: The `Response` belonging to the `WebException` only become available when the `WebException` is raised.  You can't use it before-hand because it doesn't exist at that point.  You can use it inside the `catch` section though...

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to catch any exceptions inside the `try` block. It's possible to `DoSomething()` inside the `catch` block, though.

```
try
{
    DoTheUsual();
}
catch(WebException webEx)
{
    //we won't need an if condition in here because we have the exception
    DoSomething();
}
```

**OR** you can throw a `finally` block at the end, that will **always** execute, no matter what. So we'll definitely need to check the condition to see if response is not null.

```
WebException response = new WebException();
try
{
    DoTheUsual();
}
catch(WebException webEx)
{
    response = webEx;
}
finally
{
    //If an exception occured, DoSomething() will execute, 
    //else your code will move on
    if (response != null) DoSomething();
}
```